# A definition of the homotopy colimit of a coherent diagram

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, higher-category-theory, coherence

Suppose I am given a homotopy coherent diagram of spaces of shape $I$ (This is a simplicial functor $F:\mathfrak{C}[I] \to Top$, where $\mathfrak{C}$ is the standard cofibrant replacement functor in simplicial categories as in Lurie's HTT). There are several (equivalent) formulations or constructions of the homotopy colimit of the diagram $F$.

In [this](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1107.5213.pdf) paper, it says that you can define the homotopy colimit as follows. First, define the (ordinary) category of cones over $F$, whose objects are coherent cones over $F$ (i.e. extensions of $F$ to a coherent diagram $\hat{F}$ over the category obtained from $I$ by adding additional terminal object $*$) with morphisms being maps between the end points $f:\hat{F}(*)\to \hat{G}(*)$, such that the cone $\hat{G}$ is induced from $\hat{F}$ by "composing" with $f$ in the (hopefully) obvious way. Now, this category has an initial object and it is the homotopy colimit of the diagram $F$ [Definition 3.1]. It then proves that this coincides with the Bousfield-Kan style definition [Theorem 4.1].

My question is, where can I find a "standard" reference for this fact? I am aware of some of the standard literature on coherent diagrams (Vogt, Cordier, Porter,...), but I couldn't find this specific approach to the homotopy colimit.

Remark: I am actually more interested in the homotopy limit, but it should be completely analogues.

Comment: Dwyer-Spalinski is a good place to learn about homotopy (co)limits. Hirschhorn's book too. I'm not sure, but I'll bet there is a discussion in May-Ponto as well.

Comment: I added a tag to clarify that I am looking for a reference for a specific result and not to learn about homotopy colimits in general.  Dwyer-Spalinski treat only homotopy colmits of strict diagrams (by projective/injective model structure on the category of diagrams). Hirschhorn has some explicit simplicial formulas, but I can't see if any of them gives what I am looking for. May-Punto does not seem to cover coherent diagrams at all.

Comment: What makes you think there is another reference for this fact in the first place?  Steimle makes it pretty clear in the introduction (“the model for the homotopy colimit is in the spirit of the original definition of Vogt [12], with an emphasis on universal properties”) that this is his original contribution.

Comment: Well, when you put it this way... I don't know. I wasn't sure which part exactly is an original contribution and which is just a cleaner presentation of classical stuff. I just assumed that something like this, is probably mentioned, even if in an obscure way, in the standard literature. But perhaps it isn't.

Comment: Perhaps I could benefit from some clarification. What's the distinction between the result you'd like a reference to and theorem 5.12 in Vogt's "Homotopy limits and colimits," which asserts that the homotopy colimit functor is left adjoint to the "constant diagram" functor from spaces to coherent $I$-diagrams of spaces?

Comment: 5.12 in Vogt is a claim on the level of *homotopy categories*. It says that you have an adjunction between ho(Top) and ho(Coherent diagrams in Top) given by the constant diagram and the homotopy colimit. Steimle's constructs the homotopy colimit as an initial object in a strict category of coherent cones. Maybe it is related, but I don't see how.

Comment: Ah, fair enough. This builds on 5.4(c), which looks like it might be wrangled into the unit of an adjunction by taking your target diagram E to be a constant diagram. I don't know if a reference in the literature makes the verification that you want: that functors from of the Bousfield-Kan hocolim to Z are identical with coherent cones with final point mapped to Z.